# How to change navigationBar background color on UIImagePickerController iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to change navigationBar background color on UIImagePickerController and it seems like all previous approaches don't work anymore on the last version of iOS. I don't need a global solution (via AppDelegate) because I want to keep the previous colors of other navBar's.
The following code works ok on iOS <12.3 but deals no effect on iOS 13 and navBar remains translucent white all time.

```
class CustomImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController {

    // MARK: - Override Properties

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return .darkContent
        }
        return .lightContent
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private Methods

    private func setup() {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.appPurpleColor
            navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
            navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
            navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        } else {
            navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.appPurpleColor
            navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.appPurpleColor
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Will you be using SwiftUI?

Comment: @STerrier no, I'm not planning to use SwiftUI